# Проблема с Angular2 Material dialog

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript, material-design, dialogfragment

Возникла проблема при добавлении компонента модального окна в angular 2. Окно создается, но не диалоговое.

Скрин

[image: скрин диалога]

Добавляется как обычный блок div. В чем может быть проблема?

app.module.ts

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
    DialogComponent
 ],
  imports: [
    ...
    MaterialModule.forRoot()
  ]
})
```

dialog.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { MdDialog, MdDialogConfig, MdDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
import { DialogComponent } from '../shared/dialog.component';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'dialog-page',
    templateUrl: 'dialog.component.html'
})

export class SettingsComponent {
    dialogRef: MdDialogRef<any>;

    constructor(public dialog: MdDialog,
        public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

    open(key) {
        let config = new MdDialogConfig();
        config.viewContainerRef = this.viewContainerRef;

        this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, config);

        this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            this.dialogRef = null;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: _Добавляется как обычный блок div_ - а как должен добавляться?

Comment: @Grundy Может я не так написал. Но мне нужно диалоговое окно которое откроется поверх других елементов. Сейчас оно просто ниже всех других елементов

Comment: похоже, у тебя просто нет других элементов. кстати, не вижу в твоем модуле секции entryComponents

Comment: А цсс position: absolute не спасает ситуацию?

Comment: @ВадимСтецюк, вы смогли решить эту проблему? У меня аналогичная

Comment: @Pantera, да. Нужно подключить indigo-pink.css.
Читайте Step 4: Include a theme
https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Comment: @ВадимСтецюк, то что нужно, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему добавлением стилей. В моем случае, это было indigo-pink.css.
Подробную информацию можно найти на официальном сайте [Angular MaterialUI](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)